# Rails Soap, and Heroku.. Loading a massive wsdl for each session is just not practical

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, heroku, wsdl

I'm trying to run a soap action to ebay. Say for starters, getting the time..  (of course I could get the time from other places, but my target is ebay because I am managing product there. For testing the time will be a proof point)

The problem I have is that the WSDL is massive.. 
So store it locally right?  Ah.. but heroku doesn't let me do that. There is no file system.. Not to speak of at least..

So I'm wondering.. For SOAP with insanely large WSDL files.. How does one manage them?

NOTE: I've started out using SAVON, though I'm tied to it by any means.

---

Thought bubble...
    Can a WSDL be read from a record in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system at heroku is ephemeral, which means you can write to it**, but it's not guaranteed to stick around (your dyno might get nuked by the platform at any time).  Saying this though, a given dyno that's working fairly constantly is generally around for a few hours.

Therefore, it's fair to say that you can cache the WSDL to something like the filesystem if it's not already there and use this until you spot it's missing again (in which case something has happened on the dyno grid).

** Only tmp on Bamboo/Aspen, everywhere on Cedar

Comment: sweet.. can you give me a pointer on how to store a wsdl on the system.. I know it's above and beyond...

Comment: That's probably worth opening another question for.